# Auto-Venn Diagram text rendering

Tags: python, r

I have a mental map of something in my head and I've been trying to figure out how to program it in R and I'm stumbling a bit (maybe R is not optimal) so I'm seeking your input on this.

here's the idea:

(1) I have two lists for each day that contain two bits of information each [word, frequency] on the top 30 most used words by democrats and republicans.

(2) I would like to have a venn or euler like digram drawn that 
            (A) renders the text of the words with their font size relative to the frequency 
            ​(B) automatically puts the words used by both parties into the center part of the diagram and puts the uniquely democrat or republican words in their own parts

So far I've been using packages VennDiagram and Vennerable and Venneuler, but nothing is quite correct and the text display and autosizes eludes me.  There are some online tools that get close-ish (http://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/) but I think I'd like something I can auto-update each day.

Any ideas?

Comment: One possibility is to use a word cloud instead.

Comment: Could you use a xy plot? The y=x line holds the intersection, above/below that line the unique words for each party.

Answer (score 2):

I got bored:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FIG_SIZE = (10,6)

class word_list_venn_diagram(object):

    def __init__(self, words, fontsizes, polarities, scale=1.):
        """
        Arguments:
        ----------
            words: [str 1, ... str N]
                list of strings
            fontsizes: [float 1, ... float N]
                corresponding list of (relative) fontsizes
            polarity: [-1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1]
                corresponding list of area designations;
                polarity of 0 corresponds to intersection;
                polarities -1 and 1 correspond to the disjoint sets
            scale: float
                scales the size of the circles with respect to the text
                (w.r.t. the maximum joint height of the bounding boxes of the 3 word lists)

        Returns:
        --------
            None

        """

        self.words = np.array(words)
        self.fontsizes = np.array(fontsizes)

        # get bounding boxes of text
        self.bboxes = [self._get_bbox(word, size) for word, size in zip(self.words, self.fontsizes)]

        # determine minimum radius of circles
        diameter = 0.
        unique_polarities = np.unique(polarities)
        for polarity in unique_polarities:
            idx, = np.where(polarities == polarity)
            heights = [self.bboxes[ii].height for ii in idx]
            total = np.sum(heights)
            if total > diameter:
                diameter = total
        radius = diameter / 2.

        # rescale
        radius *= scale
        self.radius = radius

        # arrange bboxes vertically
        for polarity in unique_polarities:
            idx, = np.where(polarities == polarity)
            order = self._argsort(self.fontsizes[idx])
            heights = [self.bboxes[ii].height for ii in idx]
            total = np.sum(heights)

            current_height = 0.
            for ii in idx[order]:
                self.bboxes[ii].y = current_height - total/2.
                current_height += self.bboxes[ii].height

        # arrange bboxes horizontally
        # NB: slightly cheeky use of polarity argument
        for ii, _ in enumerate(self.bboxes):
            self.bboxes[ii].x = polarities[ii] * self._get_shift(self.bboxes[ii].y, self.radius)

        # draw
        self.fig, self.ax = self.draw()

        return

    def draw(self):
        """
        Draws the Venn diagram.
        """

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=FIG_SIZE)

        # draw circles
        circle_left = plt.Circle((-0.5*self.radius, 0), self.radius, color='b', fill=False, axes=ax, linewidth=5)
        circle_right = plt.Circle((+0.5*self.radius, 0), self.radius, color='r', fill=False, axes=ax, linewidth=5)
        ax.add_artist(circle_left)
        ax.add_artist(circle_right)

        # draw words
        for ii, (word, bb, fs) in enumerate(zip(self.words, self.bboxes, self.fontsizes)):
            ax.text(bb.x, bb.y, word,
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center',
                    fontsize=fs,
                    bbox=dict(pad=0., facecolor='none', edgecolor='none')
            )

        # update data limits as circles are not registered automatically
        corners = (-1.5*self.radius, -self.radius), (1.5*self.radius, self.radius)
        ax.update_datalim(corners)
        ax.autoscale_view()

        # make figure pretty-ish
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.get_figure().set_facecolor('w')
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
        ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()

        return fig, ax

    def _get_bbox(self, word, fontsize):
        """
        Get the bounding box for each word.
        Unfortunately, the bbox is dependent on the renderer,
        so a figure has to be created.
        """
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=FIG_SIZE)
        renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
        text = plt.text(0.5, 0.5, word,
                        fontsize=fontsize,
                        bbox=dict(pad=0., facecolor='none', edgecolor='red'))
        bbox = text.get_window_extent(renderer=renderer)
        plt.close(fig)
        return bbox

    def _argsort(self, arr):
        """
        Returns indices to create a sorted array.
        Entries are sorted in such a way that the largest element is in the middle,
        and the size of the elements falls off towards the ends.
        """
        order = np.argsort(arr)
        order = np.r_[order[::2], order[1::2][::-1]]
        return order

    def _get_shift(self, y, r):
        """
        Get point along midline of a waxing moon formed by two overlapping
        circles of radius r as a function of y.
        """
        x1 = np.sqrt(r**2 - y**2) + r/2. # right circle
        x2 = np.sqrt(r**2 - y**2) - r/2. # left circle
        x = x2 + (x1 - x2)/2. # midpoint
        return x

def test():

    test_string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."

    # get a word list
    words = test_string.split(' ')

    # remove non alphanumeric characters
    words = [''.join(ch for ch in word if ch.isalnum()) for word in words]

    # count occurrences; remove duplicates
    from collections import Counter
    counter = Counter()
    for word in words:
        counter[word] += 1
    words, counts = counter.keys(), np.array(counter.values())

    # convert counts to reasonable fontsizes
    max_fontsize = 25
    max_count = np.float(np.max(counts))
    fontsizes = counts / max_count * max_fontsize

    # assign random polarities
    polarities = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], len(words))

    venn = word_list_venn_diagram(words, fontsizes, polarities, scale=1.5)

    return
```